# Java: Strings generated by substring not treated as hard coded strings

Tags: java, android, string

Dear all, I'm making a simple file decoder for Android 2.2 that needs to find the filename of the encoded file from a header. This filename should then be used as the filename for the decoded file (as you would expect).

The filename is identified by the substring `name=`, so the actual name starts 5 places after that. The line is read by a BufferedReader and temporarily stored in `currLine`.

For some reason I can't understand nor find on the web, Strings do not always seem to be Strings...

When I give the filename as

`String fileOutName = "testfile.txt";

System.out.println("fileOutName contains: "+ fileOutName);

  System.out.println("fileOutName type: "+ fileOutName.getClass());`

It works like it should. However reading it from the file does not work:

`String fileOutName = currLine.substring((currLine.indexOf("name=")+5));`

Gives no output file, nor an IO exception. The string is parsed properly though: from the System.out debugging lines I find for both cases:

`fileOutName contains: testfile.txt

fileOutName type: class java.lang.String`

Anyone have any clue as to why this would not work? :S

Thanks

Comment: Are you specifying the correct path?

Comment: can you please post a code snippet when you  read the file header?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh... Of course the `substring` routine was also getting the `end of line` character which obviously can't be in a filename but apparently is not returned by printline :)

So it's fixed by:

`String fileOutName = currLine.substring((currLine.indexOf("name=")+5), currLine.length() -1);`

Thanks for looking at this and commenting, just by posing the question the answer hit me... Can anyone please flag my answer as correct? I can't do that for the next two days it seems.

Comment: nobody except you can mark your answer as correct. Just wait for couples of days =)

Comment: In stead of currLine.length() -1 you might consider the String.trim() method. That way all leading and trailing whitespace is removed. To me that's a bit more readable :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! @extraneon - I'll use the -1 still though, as the format allows for whitespace. After name=, all characters should be treated as being the desired name, except the EOL which I included before of course. I'll keep it in mind for the future though as it's definitely more readable, thanks :)